# Eigenvalue problem in Hilbert Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, eigenvalue

In [page 71](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%2520-%2520Principles%2520of%2520quantum%2520mechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiB5evmx8XbAhUDcCsKHUt3AxIQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw3t59bGXXAPQE5joxcE1CKZ) of Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics, the author states the following(kindly take a look at page 70 because the following is a part of an example problem):

> The allowed eigenvectors thus form a discrete set labeled by an integer $m$: $$\psi_m(x) =\sqrt\frac{2}{L}\sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) \tag{1.10.50}$$ where we have chosen $B=\sqrt\frac{2}{L}$ so that $$\int_{0}^{L} \psi_m(x) \psi_{m'}(x) dx= \delta_{mm'}\tag{1.10.51}$$

Here, $\delta$ is *Kronecker delta*. Why is eq.(1.10.51) necessary to be satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

If $m\neq m'$ the integral is zero. That's automatic and doesn't depend on $B$.

If $m=m'$ this choice of $B$ ensures that the integral is 1, and remembering that $|\psi_m(x)|^2$ is the probability density (Born interpretation) that means that the total probability of the particle being somewhere is 1, as it must be (unitarity).

Answer (score 0):

This is simply due to the properties of the sine function.
Note that

$
\int_{0}^{L} sin(\frac{m\pi x}{L}) sin(\frac{m'\pi x}{L}) dx = \frac{1}{2} [\int_{0}^{L} dx \, cos(\frac{\pi x (m-m')}{L}) - \int_{0}^{L} dx \,cos(\frac{\pi x (m+m')}{L})]=\begin{cases}
 \frac{L}{2} \quad if \, \, m=m'   \\
0 \quad otherwise
\end{cases}                                      
$

Thereby to have a non-zero amplitude for the wave-function, $m=m'$ must be imposed.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$ is a [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator/%22Hermitian%22) operator i.e. the adjoint of $\hat{H}$ i.e. $\hat{H^\dagger}=\hat{H}$. It is a well known result in linear algebra that the eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix or operator are [orthogonal](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node140.html/%22orthogonal%22). That is why equation $(1.10.51)$ satisfies for the eigenvectors of $\hat{H}$.

Comment: The eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator need not be orthogonal in the case of degeneracy. That aside. When you mentioned orthogonal, I was automatically reminded of the inner product in the infinite-dimensional space. The integral in the question is the inner product of two eigenvectors! I get it now. Here, the author has normalized the eigenvectors by taking $B=\sqrt\frac{2}{L}$.

Comment: Yes. Surely in case of degeneracy, the orthogonality is not true.